# Deallocating object doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, class, pointers

Maybe I'm working too long but have this problem...
Let's make it abstract, real names are not important.

I've 20+ classes inheriting from its superclass, Car

```
@interface Car : NSObject;
@interface Volvo : Car;
@interface BMW : Car; etc...
```

In my game class I've property for Volvo, BMW

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) Volvo *volvo;
@property (nonatomic, strong) BMW *bmw;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Car *activeCar;
```

I create those object dynamicaly and storing activeCar in property activeCar

```
_bmw = [[BMW alloc] init];    
_activeCar = _bmw;
```

Now in restart method I want to be able nil active car, but it's not wokring even though in log I see both are pointing on the same address:

```
_activeCar = nil; // dealloc on BMW and Car is not called
// _bmw = nil; // dealloc is called properly on BMW and Car class
```

How can manage that? Is this the only solution?

```
if ([_activeGame isKindOfClass:[BMW class]])
_bmw = nil;
```

Comment: I'd suggest that your app is modeled a bit oddly;  why is the brand of car not just another attribute of an instance of a Car class?

Comment: I'm not using car in my real app. It's just for illustration of inheritance. Anyway, bmw and volvo are not just a names rather new classes with specific methods, properties etc

Comment: In general, heavy use of `isKindOfClass:` is a code smell; it indicates that the architecture of the application is quite shaky.  I would suggest reconsidering your design to try and eliminate such introspection.

Comment: I didn't use the isKindOfClass, I find this like one of the possible solution which...

Comment: @alexhadju Good!  I added the comment mostly such that other SO spelunkers would see it.   It is one of the numerous general mantras I toss out regularly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to destroy the BMW when you destroy the activeCar, then there's no sense in keeping BMW around as an ivar anyway.

```
_activeCar = [[BMW alloc] init];
```

Your current implementation wont nil out the BMW because self.bmw still has a reference to it.

Answer (score 2):

Your `activeCar` is actually always retained twice because you have 2 `strong` properties referring to it. So, you can nil the `activeCar`, but the other property will still be set.

If you don't want the car after it has become the `activeCar` then you could nil the other reference straight after setting it as the `activeCar`.

Comment: It's good idea. Is there some other solution, like setting activeCar to weak?

Comment: You could set it to `weak`, but then nilling it would have no effect (from a releasing point of view) so you'd be forced into some other mechanism (like your class check, which isn't pretty).